# Условный маппинг в AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Допустим, есть вот такое семейство классов:

```
class MainClass{
    List<SubClass> SubClasses{get;set;}
}

class SubClass{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

class DtoMainClass
{
    public List<int> Ids { get; set;}
}
```

Как мне сделать маппинг `DtoMainClass` на `MainClass` так, что бы если `DtoMainClass.Ids==null`, то создать пустую коллекцию, иначе (если не пусто) создать список `SubClass`

Нужно сделать несколько вызовов `ForMember` на одно и тоже поле с разными `Condition`?

Comment: Можно использовать Custom Mapper Resolver: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html

Comment: Если вы напишете `public List<int> Ids { get; set; } = new List<int>();`, то у вас там никогда не будет `null`, вместо этого будет пустая коллекция

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, нашел [решение](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html):

> Prevent this by using a PreCondition instead or by ensuring the custom
>   member mapping code can complete safely regardless of conditions:

```
.ForMember(d => d.ValueLength, o => o.MapFrom(s => s != null ? s.Value.Length : 0))
```